# d3.js bar chart example compiles correctly if using brackets.io text editor, however does not compile through file/folder directory

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, adobe-brackets

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

I'm emulating the code from that page onto my machine by creating a new folder, opening up notepad, copying and pasting the html code, renaming the .txt to "index.html" and opening up another .txt and copying the tsv contents into there and renaming it "data.tsv" as the html code implies.

I use brackets.io for my text editor of choice (mainly due to the live preview feature), and I notice the code compiles correctly and I am able to reproduce the chart that is visualized if I use the "Live Preview" feature (brackets opens up their own instance of Chrome web browser and it compiles your code). However, if I double-click on the "index.html" file through my natural Windows environment, it opens up my web browser (Chrome) but nothing is displayed.

I've consulted a similar question thread ([Simple bar chart d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175029/simple-bar-chart-d3)), however I am not using a fully-fledged IDE. I am just using brackets.io.

Comment: Are you using a web server? You cannot run it from file://